# Split string in mysql inside procedure

Tags: mysql

I have resumeids as string which i want to save in ResumeActivityLog table one by one row so total 6 rows.

```
var resumeids = "R2W5D16T8BRYWZKRF28,RHL1B05ZTQ546JKF0RG,RD95SY747Z89M7GN8TP,R2N54T767CZTBY79N00,RHT2GR6K0FTYTPFG985,RDH4KV5Z3WX7SV2850N";
```

For this im using procedure SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog to save multiple enteries.
How do i break this string of resumedid in single entry in every while loop iteration to generate 6 unique enteries.

**SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog(resumeids, 6);**

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog`(
    _resumeDIDs           Text,
    _totalRecords          int(11),
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT  DEFAULT 0;
    
    WHILE i < _totalRecords DO 
    INSERT INTO `ResumeActivityLog`
    ( `ResumeDID`, `CreatedOn`)
    VALUES(resumeDID, NOW());
    SET i =i +1;
    ENDWHILE;
END
```

Comment: Convert your CSV to JSON array (use CONCAT and REPLACE), parse and insert (use JSON_TABLE).

Comment: i want to do it in mysql @Akina

Comment: @Akina this fails for mysql version 5.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> -- create table
> CREATE TABLE ResumeActivityLog ( ResumeDID VARCHAR(255), CreatedOn DATETIME);
>
> -- create procedure
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog`(
>     _resumeDIDs           Text
> )
>     INSERT INTO `ResumeActivityLog` ( `ResumeDID`, `CreatedOn`)
>     SELECT ResumeDID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>     FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(_resumeDIDs, ',', '","'), '"]'),
>                     '$[*]' COLUMNS (ResumeDID VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable;
>
> -- call procedure with CSV as a parameter
> CALL SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog('R2W5D16T8BRYWZKRF28,RHL1B05ZTQ546JKF0RG,RD95SY747Z89M7GN8TP,R2N54T767CZTBY79N00,RHT2GR6K0FTYTPFG985,RDH4KV5Z3WX7SV2850N');
>
> -- check for the result
> SELECT * FROM ResumeActivityLog;
> ```
>
> | ResumeDID | CreatedOn |
> | --- | --- |
> | R2W5D16T8BRYWZKRF28 | 2022-07-18 09:50:28 |
> | RHL1B05ZTQ546JKF0RG | 2022-07-18 09:50:28 |
> | RD95SY747Z89M7GN8TP | 2022-07-18 09:50:28 |
> | R2N54T767CZTBY79N00 | 2022-07-18 09:50:28 |
> | RHT2GR6K0FTYTPFG985 | 2022-07-18 09:50:28 |
> | RDH4KV5Z3WX7SV2850N | 2022-07-18 09:50:28 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a412e8fcc8bc593eb3cf491a13359f37)*

PS. I'd define `CreatedOn` column as auto-utilized.

---

> this fails for mysql version 5.7.2 – art

> ```
> -- create procedure
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `SaveMultipleResumeActivityLog`(
>     _resumeDIDs           Text
> )
> BEGIN
> REPEAT
>     INSERT INTO `ResumeActivityLog` ( `ResumeDID`, `CreatedOn`)
>     SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(_resumeDIDs, ',', 1), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
>     SET _resumeDIDs = SUBSTRING(_resumeDIDs FROM LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_resumeDIDs, ',', 1))+2);
> UNTIL _resumeDIDs = '' END REPEAT;
> END
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a3b1a1e3cdf63ade4f9a894faed54d02)*

Comment: this fails for mysql version 5.7.2

Comment: @art You have not provided your MySQL version, so I can assume that you use actual version.

Comment: @art Variant for version 5.7 added.